# How to invoke a function on clicking a div?

Tags: javascript

I want a function to be invoked when I click on a `div`.

I have the functions `arti1()`,`arti2()`,`arti3()`. So, if I click that `div`, the function on that `div` as follows:

```
<div class="random" onclick="rondom()">Random</div></div>

    function rondom(){

        var rndm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
        arti+rndm+().css("display", "block");
        }
```

How can I display that random function?

Comment: What's the purpose of having all those random functions? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Are you trying to display `#arti1` element or call `function arti1(){}` ? What is expected result of `.css("display", "block")` ?

Comment: cal funtion.so here i have that div random.if i click that,wanna to random call function.the content of arti1(),arti2() was a article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div class="random" onclick="rondom()">Random</div></div>`

```
function rondom(){

    var rndm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    eval("arti"+rndm+"().css(\"display\", \"block\")");
    }
```

## Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval () or put your
functions inside an array

```
 function rondom(){

   var rndm = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
    eval ('arti'+rndm+'().css("display", "block")');
    }
```